# filter a json file to get certain objects in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

There are many country codes in this json file. I only want country codes "TWN" and "HK". I understand that TWN and HK are the object.key. however i also want to retrieve whatever that is inside the country code - e.g. the object.value of TWN
Can someone help me? I cant seem to get the results that i want. This in react native language and this is the json file https://covid.ourworldindata.org/data/owid-covid-data.json . Can someone help me?
[image]

Comment: [`Object.keys(data)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the keys of the overall object.

All you need is the [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function.

```js
const owid = {"AFG":{x:1, y:2}, "CA":{a:3, b:4}};
const countryCodes = Object.keys(owid);
console.log(countryCodes)
```

Comment: Hi, i understood it but i want to get the data for countryCodes too. for example i want AFG object data too. is there a way?